# "High quality" usage

Tags: phrase-usage

According to http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/something-is-of-high-quality ,

> It is high quality.

or

> It is of high quality.

are both OK, but clearly the first is ungrammatical. Is it really normal to say the first, or sounds a little bit odd and is used seldomly?

Comment: I find it odd that although use of the word ***seldom*** has [massively declined over the past couple of centuries](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seldomly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseldomly%3B%2Cc0), the (outrageously non-idiomatic, imho) use of the explicitly adverbial form ***seldomly*** has significantly *increased* over the past few decades. But I kinda doubt this reflects anything more than an increasing proportion of non-native speakers writing texts in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You made me wonder why I wrote *seldomly* instead of *seldom*. I'm pretty sure I learned and used to use seldom before, I must have heard *adj-ly* a lot to the point I changed it unconsciously.

Comment: Well, it's true most style guides still tell you to include ***of*** in your example, but I'm sure that's a matter of (outdated?) style, not "grammar". In fact, with the [informal](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s+good+quality%2Cit%27s+of+good+quality&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20good%20quality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20of%20good%20quality%3B%2Cc0) version (***it's*** rather than ***it is***), we decisively dumped ***of*** decades ago. So it's your ***seldomly*** that looks odd, not the missing ***of***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is high quality.

There is nothing wrong with this.  *Quality* is an adjective and *high* is an adverb modifying *quality*.  Adjectives are OK after *to be* since *to be* is a copular verb and can take subject complements.

> It is of high quality

It's also fine for a subject complement to be a prepositional phrase.  The prepositional phrase's object is the sentence's subject.

So, what's the difference in meaning?

"X is high quality" - You are saying X has the attribute *high quality.*  No implication, and this is best if the attribute *high quality* is inherent to X.

"X is of high quality" - You are implying X has the attribute *high quality* compared to those in group of other X's, or you are implying something used to make X has given X the attribute *high quality*.